# Frum travel guide - Philadelphia

Tags: product-recommendation, travel

Next week I will go to Philadelphia, and I don't know the place. Since other sites tend to be outdated, I thought that we may help each other by listing synagogues and restaurants, whenever someone travels abroad. Therefore I would like to ask those, who know Philadelphia, to give me some ideas. I'm mainly interested in Ashkenaz (but feel free to add others).

To facilitate my job, give one single answer and edit that one. Please list location, available days and branch for synagogues, style for restaurants and focus on the city centre.

[See my entry on Meta.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/helping-travellers)

Comment: http://www.philly-direct.com/frum/

Comment: @rosends Thanks indeed! However, I wrote a few weeks ago to a shul close to my place from a similar list, but never got answer.

Comment: http://www.godaven.com/list.asp?fpdbr_0_pMv=First&Name=Philadelphia%2C+PA

Comment: Commentless downvoter, why?

Comment: Seems off-topic as a better fit for Travel.SE, or primarily opinion-based, or too broad, or multiple of the above.

Comment: @DonielF It would have been nice to read your opinion on Meta.

Comment: @Kazibácsi ...Totally missed that link at the bottom. I will be happy to elaborate over there, if you want.

Comment: That said, having thought about this for a bit, I’m starting to question whether I was correct in my close vote decision, given that Jewish Life questions are indeed on-topic. In that vein, I think I will submit a reopen request.

Comment: @DonielF I didn't know, whether it was on-topic or not, that's why I asked it there. For two weeks only msh210 was interested, nobody else replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Synagogues](http://www.philly-direct.com/frum/shul.html) and [Restaurants](http://www.jewishphilly.com/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/310343/jewish/Food.htm). If you like Israeli style felafel type stuff, Mama's Vegetarian in center city Philadelphia is affordable, consistent and tasty. Take out or eat-in. Enjoy your visit.

DANF] I can vouch for the New Harmony Vegetarian Restaurant in Chinatown (downtown area). They are vegetarian, and they had a reliable hechsher as of about 4 years ago, last time I was there. I thought they were quite good.

The Swiss Haus Bakery in downtown Philly (I think it was around S 19 St.) was under International Kosher, as of about 4 years ago. I don't know what its status is now. But, if it's still kosher, some of their cupcakes were so good, I would specifically travel to Philadelphia just for them.

Downtown area has picked up quite a number of kosher places within the last few years. Otherwise, the kosher places tend to be clustered around Castor Ave. in NE Philly.

**Kazi:** I attended [Mekor Habracha,](http://mekorhabracha.org/) which is not a kapoteh and shtreimel place, but is packed with young and nice people on Shabbat. For the less religious [Beth Zion - Beth Israel](https://bzbi.org/) may be a good option. The 1818 Market Street minyan was also a good choice for weekday mincha. I've heard good things of Mama's Vegetarian, even though they accept only cash. [Hey Hummus](https://heyhummus.com/) is serving meat as well, it has an IKC hekhsher (please decide, whether you consider that reliable). It seemed to me that Hamifgash was closed, while [Swiss Haus](https://www.facebook.com/swisshaus/photos/a.207467501858.128529.185438116858/10154727761241859/?type=3) received again heksher under IKC. I found that [Rittenhouse Market](https://rittenhousemarkets.com/) was selling quite many kosher products, including bread, dairy stuff and grape juice.

Comment: Do you know by chance a synagogue with a particularly good rabbi/chazan/atmosphere?

Comment: In center city, for Shabbat, in my opinion the pickings are slim. You might enjoy Lower Merion Synagogue or Chabad of the Main Line with Rabbi Shraga Sherman. The communities are nice. The hospitality is good and they usually have some kind of interesting programs going on.

Comment: I've found this regarding the bakery:
http://mekorhabracha.org/2017/02/13/Swiss-Hause-Not-Kosher.html

Comment: To my knowledge, IKC Kosher is not considered reliable as a supervising agency.

Comment: Hamifgash seems to be out of business...

Comment: New Harmony Vegetarian is supervised by Rabbinical Assembly, Mid-Atlantic Region. This is a Conservative Movement organization. There is no Orthodox supervision there.

Comment: Whatever is the case, it's closed on Wednesdays. I was just there, forgotten to write up the name of the rabbi.